# Find the derivative of y when y= ln (arccosh x)

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I want to know how to find the derivative of y when y= ln (arccosh x) 
I know arccosh x = 1/[x^2 -1]^(1/2)
So 
1/[(arccosh x)^[2] [x^2 -1]^(1/2)]
But the right answer is 
1/[(arccosh x)^[2] [x^2 -1]^(1/2)]

Why?

Please help

Thanks all

Comment: Do you know what the derivative of $\operatorname{arccosh}$ is? And then can you apply the chain rule?

Comment: @Bongers thanks, please see what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have : y = ln[arccosh(x)]. Define z = arccosh(x), then y = ln[z]; so the derivative of y with respect to z is just (dy/dz) = 1 / z. Now, the derivative of z with respect to x is (dz/dx) = 1 / Sqrt[x^2 - 1]. Now, apply the chain rule (dy/dx) = (dy/dz) (dz/dx).